# How to add SDL2 libaries in arch-based linux

Tags: c++, sdl, manjaro

I write some code for just empty window in SDL2.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char ** arg){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window * win = SDL_CreateWindow("title", 30, 30, 600, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Surface * screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I am in Arch-based Linux (manjaro gnome). I downloaded all files with SDL2 from package manager (smaller AUR). And I think I need to add something to root folder where my main.cpp. But where I need to search this files? I don't find tutorials for SDL2 on arch linux. I am working in VSCode and I just make one file main.cpp. Hello world in C++ is working so it's not problem in C++ installation. If you need error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccq0QfEp.o: in function «main»:
main.cpp:(.text+0x15): indefinite link «SDL_Init»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): indefinite link «SDL_CreateWindow»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): indefinite link «SDL_GetWindowSurface»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): indefinite link «SDL_Delay»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x69): indefinite link «SDL_DestroyWindow»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): indefinite link «SDL_Quit»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you did and what output that produced.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt indefinite link «SDL_CreateWindow» for all SDl_things

Comment: You're still paraphrasing. Also, [edit] your question and include the info there.

Comment: You need to link to the sdl libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles but how to link them?

Comment: Very interesting, searching for "indefinite link" doesn't turn up anything relevant...

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler and/or linker?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For compiling code I used Code Runner extension from vscode

Comment: Can you try it from the terminal, then again with ``LANG= `` (with space at the end) prepended? I'm just curious, maybe it's your locale affecting error messages?

Comment: The solution is to add the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` to the flags, like with most other libraries.